Recursive drawing for the Multigrid γ-cycle
I'm trying to reproduce the image here for an arbitrary choice of γ. γ=1 should give a V-cycle, γ=2 should give a W-cycle, and so on...
I've written a recursive code that I would love to keep since it's not far from what the real multigrid algorithm does.
Unfortunately I have to repeat the same code inside \Vcycle γ-times for it to work.
Is there a way to use a loop to repeat the code inside \Vcycle and get the correct figure? I mean obtaining a loop that gives the same result as repeating this snippet code manually:
    \PreSmooth
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}
    \ifnum\newlevel>\lowestLevel
    \Vcycle
    \else
    \CoarseCorrection
    \fi
    \PostSmooth

My attempts have all failed miserably. Here's the code:
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}   

  \newcommand{\psize}{3pt}
  \newcommand{\leny}{3} 
  \newcommand{\lastx}{0} 
  \newcommand{\lasty}{0} 
  \newcommand{\lowestLevel}{-3}
  \newcommand{\Ofontsize}{\Large}
  \newcommand{\Oposition}{right}

  \newcommand{\PreSmooth}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newx}{{\lastx + 1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newy}{{\lasty - \leny}}
    \draw  (\newx,\newy) -- ({\newx - 1},{\newy + \leny});
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}
    \ifnum\nextlevel>\lowestLevel
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy) / \leny))}}
    \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coeff^3}\right)$};
    \fi
    \renewcommand{\lastx}{\newx}  
    \renewcommand{\lasty}{\newy}
  }

  \newcommand{\CoarseCorrection}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy) / \leny))}}
    \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[below] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coeff^3}\right)$};
  }
  
  \newcommand{\PostSmooth}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newx}{{\lastx + 1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newy}{{\lasty + \leny}}
    \draw  (\newx,\newy) -- ({\newx - 1},{\newy - \leny});
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}
    \ifnum\nextlevel=0
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy ) / \leny))}}
    \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(p^3\right)$};
    \else
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy ) / \leny))}}
    \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coeff^3}\right)$};
    \fi
    \renewcommand{\lastx}{\newx}  
    \renewcommand{\lasty}{\newy}
  }  
  
  \newcommand{\Vcycle}{

    % HERE I WOULD LIKE TO AVOID REPEATING THESE LINES MANUALLY
    % BUT I HAVEN'T BEEN ABLE TO MAKE 
    % \LOOP, \FOREACH, \MULTIDO OR \FORLOOP WORK :(

    \PreSmooth
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}
    \ifnum\newlevel>\lowestLevel
    \Vcycle
    \else
    \CoarseCorrection
    \fi
    \PostSmooth

    \PreSmooth
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}
    \ifnum\newlevel>\lowestLevel
    \Vcycle
    \else
    \CoarseCorrection
    \fi
    \PostSmooth

  }   
  
  \filldraw  (0,0) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(p^3\right)$};  
  \Vcycle
  
\end{tikzpicture}
}


Found it! It's not perfect by any means but it works!
Basically the code must be expanded before the interpretation of the macros starts. \foreach, \forloop, \loop and \multido didn't work for me for this.
Here's the figure and the code:

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   

  \newcommand{\BeginGammaCycle}{\GammaCycle{2}}   
  \newcommand{\lowestLevel}{-3}

  \newcommand{\pointSize}{3pt}
  \newcommand{\stepHeight}{3} 
  \newcommand{\lastx}{0} 
  \newcommand{\lasty}{0} 
  \newcommand{\Ofontsize}{\Large}
  \newcommand{\Oposition}{right}

  \newcommand{\PreSmooth}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{{\lastx + 1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{{\lasty - \stepHeight}}
    \draw  (\x,\y) -- ({\x - 1},{\y + \stepHeight});
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextlevel}{{\y / \stepHeight}}
    \ifnum\nextlevel>\lowestLevel
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coarseningFactor}{{(2^((-\y) / \stepHeight))}}
    \filldraw  (\x,\y) circle (\pointSize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coarseningFactor^3}\right)$};
    \fi
    \renewcommand{\lastx}{\x}  
    \renewcommand{\lasty}{\y}
  }

  \newcommand{\CoarseCorrection}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coarseningFactor}{{(2^((-\y) / \stepHeight))}}
    \filldraw  (\x,\y) circle (\pointSize) node[below] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coarseningFactor^3}\right)$};
  }
  
  \newcommand{\PostSmooth}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{{\lastx + 1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{{\lasty + \stepHeight}}
    \draw  (\x,\y) -- ({\x - 1},{\y - \stepHeight});
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextlevel}{{\y / \stepHeight}}
    \ifnum\nextlevel=0
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coarseningFactor}{{(2^((-\y ) / \stepHeight))}}
    \filldraw  (\x,\y) circle (\pointSize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(p^3\right)$};
    \else
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coarseningFactor}{{(2^((-\y ) / \stepHeight))}}
    \filldraw  (\x,\y) circle (\pointSize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coarseningFactor^3}\right)$};
    \fi
    \renewcommand{\lastx}{\x}  
    \renewcommand{\lasty}{\y}
  }  

  \newcommand{\GammaCycle}[1]{
    \ifnum#1>0
    \PreSmooth
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newlevel}{{\y / \stepHeight}}
    \ifnum\newlevel>\lowestLevel
    \BeginGammaCycle
    \else
    \CoarseCorrection
    \fi
    \PostSmooth
    \expandafter\GammaCycle\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}
    \fi
  }

  \filldraw  (0,0) circle (\pointSize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(p^3\right)$};  
  \BeginGammaCycle
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I hope it teaches @ms-spo something about recursion! ;)

Would you mind making your code compile? And perhaps add a screenshot? Both help this community. Thank you

@MS-SPO There you go! I hope this lets you understand recursion! :)

Two approaches:

W curve = <max level> and W curve* = <max level>: a recursive operation that draws that W curve up to level <max level> (starting with level 0). The  starred version places the final dot/label at level 0. This allows combination of two W curves:
\draw (0,0) [W curve = 2, W curve* = 2];`


W curvey = {<sequence>}: draws a W curve following the <sequence> which consists of d and u for a step down or up, <n> = [du] which places <n> steps of either d or u and * = <n>[du][ud] which places <n> steps of [du] and then <n> steps of [ud] which allows you to draw the graphs, for example:
\draw (0,0) [W curvey={5=d, */.list={1ud, ...ud, 5ud}, 5=u}];



The styles W curve dot and W curve node describe how the dots and the nodes should look like.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  W curve dot/.style n args={3}{shape=circle, fill, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+3pt, label={[W curve node={#1}{#2}{#3}]}},
  W curve node/.style n args={3}{inner sep=+.15em, scale=.5, label position={\ifnum#1>#2 below\else right\fi},
    node contents={$\mathcal O \ifnum#1=0 (p^3)\else\bigl(\frac{p^3}{#3^{3}}\bigr)\fi$}},
  %%% W curve = <level> (recursive)
  W curve/.style={W curve/do={0}{#1}{1}},
  W curve*/.style={W curve={#1}, insert path={node[W curve dot=000]{}}}, % final
  W curve/up/.style n args={3}{insert path={node[W curve dot={#1}{#2}{#3}]{}--++(1,1)}},
  W curve/do/.style n args={3}{
    insert path={
      node[W curve dot={#1}{#2}{#3}]{} -- ++(1,-1)
      \ifnum#1<#2 [W curve/do/.expanded={\inteval{#1+1}}{#2}{\inteval{#3*2}}]
                  [W curve/do/.expanded={\inteval{#1+1}}{#2}{\inteval{#3*2}}] \fi
      [W curve/up/.expanded={\inteval{#1+1}{#2}{\inteval{#3*2}}}]}},
  %%% W curvey, steps with: d, u, <n>=[du] or *=<n>[du][ud]
  W curvey/.code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/W curvey}{clevel=0,frac=1,#1,@end dot},
  W curvey/tikz/.code=\tikzset{#1},
  W curvey/.unknown/.code=\expanded{\noexpand\pgfkeysalso{#1/.list={1, ..., \pgfkeyscurrentname}}},
  W curvey/clevel/.initial=0, W curvey/frac/.initial=1, W curvey/level/.initial=4,
  W curvey/@end dot/.style={/tikz/insert path={node[W curve dot={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/W curvey/clevel}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/W curvey/level}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/W curvey/frac}}]{}}},
  W curvey/d/.style={
    tikz={insert path={node[W curve dot={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/W curvey/clevel}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/W curvey/level}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/W curvey/frac}}]{}--++(1,-1)}},
    clevel/.++, frac/.*2},
  W curvey/u/.style={
    tikz={W curve/up={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/W curvey/clevel}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/W curvey/level}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/W curvey/frac}}},
    clevel/.--, frac/.d2},
  W curvey/*/.style n args={3}{#2/.list={1, ..., #1}, #3/.list={1, ..., #1}},
  %%% PGFKeys tools for W curvey
  /handlers/.++/.code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\inteval{\pgfkeysvalueof{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}+1}},
  /handlers/.--/.code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\inteval{\pgfkeysvalueof{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}-1}},
  /handlers/.*2/.code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\inteval{\pgfkeysvalueof{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}*2}},
  /handlers/.d2/.code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\inteval{\pgfkeysvalueof{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}/2}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm]
\draw (0,0) [W curve=2, W curve*=2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=4mm, x=2.5mm, W curve node/.style=coordinate]
\draw (0,0) [W curvey={5=d, */.list={1ud, ...ud, 5ud}, 5=u}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output



This is a great answer I'm sure, I'll study it closer. I'm having a terrible time to understand the syntax but it's probably a problem on my end

A few remarks, far from being a solution yet.
Use non-aggressive (defensive) programming
Code, especially in unchartered territory (for myself), can hurt easily, i.e. doesn't work, runs wild etc.
A means to counter this is at least to visualize what your code is doing ("understanding" at a glance). Well proven tools are:

indenting in a systematic way (e.g. if-content indented; see code below) // structured programming
using comments (even more frequently than you did)
refactoring (generalizing things which repeat or are very similar)

If you do so, the structure (or missing/flawed structure in this case, see recursion) is more easy to grasp,
Recursion
I didn't see THIS (pseudocodish) structure in your code (!)
def factorial(n):                      % "function"
    if n > 0:                          % read: as-long-as
        return n * factorial(n - 1)    % SAME function + decrement
    else:
        return 1                       % STOP condition

(From Wikipedia)
What you present, is not recursive so far ... at least it is very hard to spot, and may or may not end up in an endless compile (who can read that from your code?). It's also hard to tell, where to improve it.
Best will be restarting from scractch. Which means: you have to formalize to continuous fragmentation of a given segment (which you can draw some times later, i.e. in the end).
This is the reason why I didn't even dare to compile your code.
Parameters for \Vcycle
You want 2 parameters, but you didn't use them ...
You also should end each line by % within a \newcommand to avoid spurious insertion of spaces during expansion, though Tikz seems to care not so much about spaces.
Suggestions
(1) To learn about recursion problems wrt Tikz you may want to inspect some of these search results: [recursion] tikz.
(2) Try a bottom-up approach WITH refactoring, like e.g. illustrated here. I.e. start with aboves pseudocode structure, replace it step by step, yield simple  results first, refine.
(3) Separate data to be calculated from graphical representation. E.g.

your recursion could generate a list of x- and y-data (which may or may not be Tikz' \coordinates
later you can draw them with Tikz
use class standalone, as you will probably have an undefined width of your drawing


Making your code "talk" a bit more:
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}   

  \newcommand{\psize}{3pt}
  \newcommand{\leny}{6} 
  \newcommand{\lastx}{0} 
  \newcommand{\lasty}{0} 
  \newcommand{\lowestLevel}{-6}
  \newcommand{\Ofontsize}{\Large}
  \newcommand{\Oposition}{right}
  
  \newcommand{\Vcycle}[2]{% do you use parameters at all?

    % Begin of the code that is repeated gamma times

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newx}{{\lastx + 1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newy}{{\lasty - \leny}}
    \draw  (\newx,\newy) -- ({\newx - 1},{\newy + \leny});
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}
    \ifnum\nextlevel>\lowestLevel
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy + 1) / \leny)}}
        \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coeff^3}\right)$};
    \else
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy) / \leny)}}
        \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[below] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coeff^3}\right)$};
    \fi
    
    
    \renewcommand{\lastx}{\newx}  
    \renewcommand{\lasty}{\newy}

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}
    \ifnum\newlevel>\lowestLevel
        \Vcycle{\newx}{\newy}  
    \fi

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newx}{{\lastx + 1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newy}{{\lasty + \leny}}
    \draw  (\newx,\newy) -- ({\newx - 1},{\newy - \leny});
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}
    
    \ifnum\nextlevel=0
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy + 1) / \leny)}}
        \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(p^3\right)$};
    \else
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy + 1) / \leny)}}
        \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coeff^3}\right)$};
    \fi
    
    
    \renewcommand{\lastx}{\newx}  
    \renewcommand{\lasty}{\newy}

    % End of the code that is repeated gamma times.

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newx}{{\lastx + 1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newy}{{\lasty - \leny}}
    \draw  (\newx,\newy) -- ({\newx - 1},{\newy + \leny});
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}
    
    \ifnum\nextlevel>\lowestLevel
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy + 1) / \leny)}}
        \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coeff^3}\right)$};
    \else
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy) / \leny)}}
        \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[below] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coeff^3}\right)$};
    \fi
    
    \renewcommand{\lastx}{\newx}  
    \renewcommand{\lasty}{\newy}  

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}
    
    \ifnum\newlevel>\lowestLevel
        \Vcycle{\newx}{\newy}  
    \fi

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newx}{{\lastx + 1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newy}{{\lasty + \leny}}
    \draw  (\newx,\newy) -- ({\newx - 1},{\newy - \leny});
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextlevel}{{\newy / \leny}}

    \ifnum\nextlevel=0
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy + 1) / \leny)}}
        \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(p^3\right)$};
    \else
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\coeff}{{(2^((-\newy + 1) / \leny)}}
        \filldraw  (\newx,\newy) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{p^3}{\coeff^3}\right)$};
    \fi
    
    \renewcommand{\lastx}{\newx}  
    \renewcommand{\lasty}{\newy}
  }  % ~~~ end of \Vcycle ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  
  \filldraw  (0,0) circle (\psize) node[\Oposition] {\Ofontsize$\mathcal{O}\left(p^3\right)$};  
  \Vcycle{0}{0}
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Just added a comment where the code calls itself with 2 arguments.

@Astor, yes, you call with two arguments, but you don't use them inside \Vcycle  ... I don't see Parameters #1 or #2 being used anywhere ...

You're right! Thank you! But you see the recursion right?

@Astor, no, not really. E.g. I don't see, where and when your algorithm will stop. BTW, do you know that you can express a recursion as a loop and vice versa? Follow the approach which is easier. See e.g. here: https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html

Each call of \Vcycle will stop when the variable \newlevel is equal to the variable \lowestLevel. Check the definition of recursion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)
